# CSS animation differences between SVG/HTML elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the same object as SVG and as PNG.
I am trying to animate them with those set of rules:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-right {
  from { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
#airplane {
   transform-origin: 200px 200px;
  animation: rotate-right 6s linear 0s infinite; 
}
```

here are the animations with the same rules.
why the SVG animation looks so much better while the HTML animation looks like rotating around its own axis?

[SVG Animation](https://codepen.io/iliran11/pen/EXdRNm)

[HTML Animation](https://codepen.io/iliran11/pen/gRqpPX)

Comment: The HTML animation does not rotate around its own axis.

Comment: Your HTML version is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the same object as SVG and as PNG

No you don't.  Your animations are completely different.

1. The PNG and SVGs have completely different sizes, shapes and layout.
2. The PNG is being animated as a whole
3. The SVG is having one element within it animated.
4. `transform-origin` on a `<g>` element inside an SVG works differently from `transform-origin` on an HTML element.  Inside an SVG, it is affected by the `viewBox`.

Comment: thanks. do you know any reference for the differences between the way `transform-origin` works on svg Elemeng and HTML element?

Comment: Every coordinate in an SVG is affected by the `viewBox`. That's how SVG works. So given that, the transform-origin of `200px,200px`in the SVG corresponds to the bottom right corner of the SVG (since the `viewBox` is `"0 0 200 200"`). That applies no matter what size the SVG is being displayed at.  Your PNG however is rotating around the point (200px,200px) on the page.  How that affects the PNG will depend on how large it is, and where it is on the page.